# csv to hash, group and save to .txt by date

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I am importing a csv file of iphone logs and would like to group the calls by date and output each days calls to a .txt file.

I am importing thus:

```
src = <<csv
"name","Date","Duration","Call Type"
"Henry Jones ","2013-04-04 19:30:19","0:00:49","Outgoing"
"Alistair Morgan ","2013-04-05 13:14:07","0:00:03","Outgoing"
"Quentin Blah","2013-04-05 13:19:44","0:04:28","Missed"
"Quentin Blah","2013-04-05 13:25:19","0:09:45","Incoming"
"Henry Jones ","2013-04-05 14:35:29","0:00:24","Incoming"
"Henry Jones ","2013-04-05 15:54:53","0:00:00","Missed"
"Henry Jones ","2013-04-06 16:21:20","0:00:47","Outgoing"
"Bill and Ben Saunders ","2013-04-06 18:33:00","0:00:32","Outgoing"
"Phil Philly","2013-04-08 08:56:06","0:01:18","Outgoing"
"Barry Smith ","2013-04-08 13:51:03","0:00:48","Incoming"
"John Goole ","2013-04-08 18:24:57","0:06:28","Incoming"
"John Goole ","2013-04-08 18:32:07","0:00:35","Outgoing"
"Barry Barry","2013-04-08 18:33:29","0:01:56","Outgoing"
"Phil Michelson","2013-04-09 09:32:14","0:20:30","Outgoing"
"Nick Badson ","2013-04-09 12:00:28","0:00:00","Incoming"
"Henry Jones ","2013-04-09 15:09:02","0:00:00","Outgoing"
csv

require 'csv'
csv_data = CSV.parse (src)

headers = csv_data.shift.map {|i| i.to_s }
string_data = csv_data.map {|row| row.map {|cell| cell.to_s } }
array_of_hashes = string_data.map {|row| Hash[*headers.zip(row).flatten] }

p array_of_hashes
```

I am struggling now to know how to sort them and then output.

Many TIA

Answer (score 1):

use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

try this

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by{|h| h["Duration"]} #=> change "Duration" any key you needed.
```

Comment: hi, this is not working the hashes still stop i the same position in the array

Comment: Just found out that it does not sort in place, but that I have to sort to a new array. Is there any way I can also print out to a different text file per day?

Comment: @NickWild what's not sorting it does., I checked.

Comment: Weird. I had to do... `Newarray=array_of_hashes.sort_by{|h| h["Duration"]}` to make it work. Not a problem, but next concern is how to output to text file according to date :-)

Comment: @NickWild search stackoverflow,you will get lots of examples.